# Symfony2, Sonata, FormMapper, add hidden field to be handled in PrePersist/PreUpdate

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I actually did some tricks so i could be able to persist a user if its ID is passed by an url parameter. (Custom action from user list).

/admin/se/api/bundle/create?**user=7**

I actually could not find how to send the user entity returned by a findByOne(array('id' => $user_id)) so i guess i'll need to pass the $user_id through a hidden field and handle its value in a PrePersist

Otherwise passing the id that way

```
->add('user', 'hidden', array('data' => $user_id))
```

will return an error :

> This value is not valid.
>
> Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).children[user] = 7
>
> Caused by:
>
> Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException
>   Compound forms expect an array or NULL on submission.

This is my first attempt that is **not** working :

```
$container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();

$request = $container->get('request');

$user_id = $request->get('user');

if(!empty($user_id)){

    $em = $this->getModelManager()->getEntityManager($this->getClass());

    $user = $em->getRepository('ApiBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('id' => $user_id));

    if($user){

        $formMapper
            ->with('User', array('description' => '<strong>User : </strong>'.$user->getDisplayName()))
                ->add('user', 'hidden', array('data' => $user_id))
                // this of course doesn't work as explained above. How can i have my own hidden input not related to any property
            ->end();

    }
```

So how would i do that? Any better solution is welcomed.

Comment: I know this question is old but wouldn't ->add("user.id", "hidden") do the trick ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is the best trick i found. I wish 'sonata_type_model_hidden' has more options. I guess i could do my own custom field to be able to do that. But i'm not sure how and anyway this solution is fast to implement.

```
$formMapper
    ->with('Guide', array('description' => '<strong>Guide : </strong>'.$guide->getDisplayName()))
        ->add('guide', 'sonata_type_model_autocomplete', array(
            'property' => array('firstname', 'lastname', 'username', 'email'),
            'data_class' => null, // IMPORTANT
            'data' => $guide,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'sonata-autocomplete-hidden'), // custom class
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'sonata-autocomplete-hidden'), // custom class
        )
    )
->end();
```

To hide the field :

```
.sonata-autocomplete-hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

If you have any better solutions, you're welcome.